# SQL dejar solo los 10 últimos registros

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

Esto forma parte de un trigger que detecta modificaciones en una BBDD.
El ultimo if debe de borrar todas las tuplas que no sean las 10 ultimas.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(ID_MOD) FROM cambiolog) > 10 THEN
    DELETE FROM cambiolog WHERE (SELECT * FROM cambiolog WHERE id_mod < (SELECT MAX(ID_MOD)FROM cambiolog)-10);
END IF;
```

Pero no consigo que compile.
La ayuda se agradece.

Comment: Hola Alejman95, me puedes decir si la respuesta dada te fue útil, gracias

Answer (score 0):

El **select** para obtener los últimos 10 registros podría ser:

```
select id_mod
from cambiolog
order by id_mod desc
limit 10
```

Se ordenan los registros **descendentemente** por el **campo id_mod**, de modo que aparezcan primero los últimos registros introducidos, y se usa la **clausula limit** para obtener de todo ese conjunto de filas solamente las 10 primeras.

Para obtener todas las tuplas que no sean las 10 ultimas entonces haríamos lo siguiente:

```
select id_mod
from cambiolog c1
where c1.cambiolog not in (                             
                           select c2.id_mod
                           from cambiolog c2
                           order by c2.id_mod desc
                           limit 10
                         )
```

Esta consulta utiliza como subconsulta la primera consulta explicada y sobre esa subconsulta se hace una consulta aplicando el operador **not in**, devolviéndose de esta forma todos los registros de la tabla que no están entre los registros devueltos por la subconsulta, es decir se obtendrían todos los registros que no son los 10 últimos introducidos.

Esta ultima consulta es la que debes poner en tu **comando delete**.

Comment: Me dices así? 'IF countID > 10 THEN
       DELETE FROM cambiolog WHERE (select id_mod from cambiolog c1 where c1.cambiolog not in (select c2.id_mod from cambiolog c2 order by c2.id_mod desc limit 10);
    END IF;' Porque no funciona: LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
13/8      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/37     PL/SQL: ORA-00936: falta una expresión
Errores: comprobar log de compilador

Comment: @Alejman95 , ya te di una respuesta que te muestra como obtener el select, ahora te toca a ti esforzarte un poco y ver como la adaptas a tus necesidades

Comment: Ve probando poco a poco, primero haz el select y mira a ver sí funciona y después, lo pones en tu delete

Comment: @Alejman95, por fin resolviste?

Comment: Si, uso la opción mas rentable. Descarte el sistema de fechas y use las id para identificar el mas antiguo.